# Nsight remote debugger settings

Tags: nsight

I am trying to setup a remote Nsight v2.2 debugger for GPU debugging only(no CUDA). I have followed this [Nvidia pdf](http://www.nvidia.com/content/siggraph/Kiel_Parallel_Nsight.pdf) for setting up the remote target machine and the development machine. All are up and running, but the communication between the two is not proper. I am getting errors like MSVSMON.exe not running on remote machine etc. I am not sure about the exact settings required. What should be the,

- VS2010 project settings
- Nsight Monitor(remote machine) settings
- Nsight Settings in VS2010 and development machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what kind of activity are you trying to do (CUDA, API or shader DX debugging)? If any of the above, there's no need for running MSVSMON.  Just make sure you:

1. Run the Nsight Monitor (on the remote system)

   - Read about other monitor options in the [Setting up remote debugging docs](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Setup_Remote_Debugging.htm)
2. (on the host side) Right click on VS 2010 project and select "Nsight user properties" and type in the remote machine name under the "connection name" setting

   - If you do not want to sync (which means it will copy files over to the target machine), then go under the "Synchronization" node and make changes there.  See the [docs on Synchronization](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Synchronization.htm)
     (Click OK to accept all the monitor changes)
3. Now you should be able to select if you wish to debug CUDA or graphics from the Nsight menu and this will launch what you need on the remote machine.

   - Note: do not do "F5" as it will launch the Microsoft (CPU) debugger

Hopefully that helps you.
If you have new/other questions, please check out the NVIDIA forums

Comment: I am setting up for the shader debugging thing.