# CUDA on Windows and Linux

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to set up a cuda development environment under windows, and lurked many cuda-tagged posts, but few things are still unclear:

- Can I debug cuda applications under windows without the need of a second video card, using nsight and VS2010 express?
- Can I debug cuda applications under linux  without the need of a second video card, *AND* without shut down the graphical interface?
- Answered thousands of times, but perhaps something has changed, so I ask again just to be sure: Can I develop under windows without installing a cuda-enabled video card? There is some kind of emeulator? (Ocelot for windows is practically inexistent).

Thanks.

Comment: I really don't think you can use NSight with Express, with or without a second video card.  For that very reason I installed Linux and got Eclipse/Nsight up and running, but I wasn't able to accomplish the debugging aspect in the scenario you describe (I was able to run the profiler).  However, others have said that it's possible so it's likely I was just missing something.

Comment: I think debugging under linux with one vidcard is only possible by working in console mode, at least for the debugging session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I debug cuda applications under windows without the need of a second video card, using nsight and VS2010 express?

You can apparently debug with a single video card, but nsight requires vs2010 professional (not express edition)
https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-visual-studio-edition-requirements

> Can I debug cuda applications under linux without the need of a second video card, AND without shut down the graphical interface?

I don't think so, from the eclipse nsight docs (http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#linux-requirements):
"A GPU that is running X11 (on Linux) or Aqua (on Mac) cannot be used to debug a CUDA application and will be hidden from the application ran in the debugger. Such GPU can still be used for profiling GPU applications."

> Answered thousands of times, but perhaps something has changed, so I ask again just to be sure: Can I develop under windows without installing a cuda-enabled video card? There is some kind of emeulator? (Ocelot for windows is practically inexistent).

no, if you want to use cuda, you'd be best off just getting a cheap cuda-enabled card (e.g. a GTX 650 is ~$100 and is the most recent (kepler) architecture)

Comment: I already own a 660 for my desktop machine. But I would like to develop for cuda even using my windows laptop (integrated intel HD)...

Comment: Alternatively you could use  Nsight's remote CUDA debugging capability , doing the development on your laptop and executing and debugging remotely on the desktop machine.

Comment: This is good. I already considered such a solution, but thought i would have to use tools like rcuda. Glad to be aware nsight permits remote executing/debugging. Can you provide a link? A quick spotlight in the nsight docs returned no results... Thanks!

Comment: @user2157783 Have you tried what is detailed at http://http.developer.nvidia.com/NsightVisualStudio/2.2/Documentation/UserGuide/HTML/Content/Setup_Remote_Debugging.htm? Also, this is a pretty relevant SO question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159025/nsight-remote-debugger-settings

Comment: This answer is now obsolete.