# Can I connect NVIDIA Nsight to a remote machine?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, nsight

I don't have a graphics card which supports CUDA on my computer. Can I connect NVIDIA Nsight to a remote machine using `ssh` (or anything else)?

Comment: do you mean nsight VSE (windows) or nsight eclipse edition (linux/macos)?  Which OS is on the remote machine, windows or linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [Nsight Visual Studio Edition's remote debugging feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14165227/1888983)

Yes, you can use [Nsight Eclipse Edition's remote debugging feature](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/nsight-eclipse-edition-getting-started-guide/index.html#remote-debugging)